# How to not use global in python

Tags: python

My code works using global to define some variables but is there any other way to make them be defined without using global? Otherwise, I run into error's regarding variables not being defined.

Here is my code:

```
#takes list of rows of code, returns dict of alumni and grad year
def makeAlumniDict():
    global my_dict
    my_dict = {'Charell Adagala': 2018, 'Sukhneet kaur': 2018, 'Mayanka Jha': 2019,
            'Paul Cheakalos': 2018, 'Elizabeth(Liz)Boniface': 2013,
            'Kati Illieva': 2021, 'Suzy wilson': 2018, 'Ronit Gopalani': 2019}

#takes dictionary of alumni and years, returns list of alumni grads between years (inclusive)
def betweenYears():
    makeAlumniDict()
    
    names = []
    for name, date in my_dict.items():
        if start <= date <= end:
            names.append(name)
    print(names)
    

#MAIN CODE
def main():
    
    global start
    global end
    start = int(input('Start Year: '))
    end = int(input('End Year: '))


    betweenYears()
    
main()
```

Comment: define them in module level scope i.e. outside of a function

Comment: what is the point of `makeAlumniDict()`? can't You just create it outside the function? (the dictionary)

Comment: also I guess You can use functions but in this code You might as well not use them at all because they are not too benefical, You might as well write this code without any functions

Comment: @L.Grozinger, ...that's making things worse -- when the user puts variables at the module level, they need to use `global` to write to them from inside a function. Better to use classes for storage and encapsulation and avoid module-level variables altogether -- or pass arguments as parameters and return them as return values.

Comment: Functions without parameters are a warning sign that you are likely (mis)using other ways of passing parameters. I.e. don’t do this: pass the parameters the functions use _as parameters_ not globals, and return the results; store those results in variables.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy a good point. Any strategy that uses `global` is best avoided IMO. But I was thinking more of this example, where the user could declare put `my_dict = {}` at the top level, then use his functions to manipulate that `my_dict`. Would you say that is still a bad practice? Genuinely curious...

Comment: I'd call it a worse practice than separately instantiated objects, but a better practice than separate module-level variables; it's a continuum. (One of the questions I ask is "how easy is this to create N separate instances in your test suite?"; the single-module-level-global approach doesn't let you parallelize that suite, but at least does make it easy to reset it).

Answer (score 4):

You could pass variables between functions like this:

```
#takes list of rows of code, returns dict of alumni and grad year
def makeAlumniDict():
    return {'Charell Adagala': 2018, 'Sukhneet kaur': 2018, 'Mayanka Jha': 2019,
            'Paul Cheakalos': 2018, 'Elizabeth(Liz)Boniface': 2013,
            'Kati Illieva': 2021, 'Suzy wilson': 2018, 'Ronit Gopalani': 2019}

#takes dictionary of alumni and years, returns list of alumni grads between years (inclusive)
def betweenYears(start, end):
    my_dict = makeAlumniDict()
    
    names = []
    for name, date in my_dict.items():
        if start <= date <= end:
            names.append(name)
    print(names)
    

#MAIN CODE
def main():
    
    start = int(input('Start Year: '))
    end = int(input('End Year: '))

    betweenYears(start, end)
    
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, this particular problem seems to be best solved with parameters to functions and return codes. Taking it a bit further and taking hints from the comments (which I've changed to function doc strings) you could

```
def makeAlumniDict():
    """takes list of rows of code, returns dict of alumni and grad year"""
    my_dict = {'Charell Adagala': 2018, 'Sukhneet kaur': 2018, 'Mayanka Jha': 2019,
            'Paul Cheakalos': 2018, 'Elizabeth(Liz)Boniface': 2013,
            'Kati Illieva': 2021, 'Suzy wilson': 2018, 'Ronit Gopalani': 2019}
    return my_dict

def betweenYears(alum_dict, start, end):
    """takes dictionary of alumni and years, returns list of alumni grads between years (inclusive)"""
    return [name for name, date in alum_dict.items() 
        if start <= date <= end]
    
#MAIN CODE
def main():
    start = int(input('Start Year: '))
    end = int(input('End Year: '))
    alum_dict = makeAlumniDict()
    my_names = betweenYears(alum_dict, start, end)
    print(my_names)
    
main()
```